# How to check value in column which has comma separated value in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, qsqlquery

I have one column named `services_id`.

The column contain comma separated values like `1,3,4,5`.

Now I want to search based on condition that if `services_id` `=` `3`  all row that contain `3` should come up in result whether it has value like `1,3,4,5` OR `3,4,5,1`.

**I have tried with `IN` operator but it gives only value which comes at first index.**

like if I searched with **`services_id IN (3)`** it return only column with value `3,4,5,1` which have `3` in its first index. **It should return column which have `3` in any index.**

**In this case result should be two row**

**1,3,4,5** AND **3,4,5,1**

Comment: Yes !! you can execute below query
`select * from YOURTABLENAME where CONCAT(',', YOURCOLUMNNAME, ',') like '%,1,%'`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad